# Upload image onclick on Mask image instead of choose file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the code below to upload the image on the mask image, so that the user needs to select the `choose file` button to upload image on mask.

**Requirement** :

But when the user clicks on the mask image, it should display the "Image upload" dialogue box & allow to upload image.

Here is a Codepen : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/ywaxVY

```js
var mask;

let jsonData = {
  "path" : " love shape\/",
  "info" : {
    "author" : "",
    "keywords" : "",
    "file" : "love shape",
    "date" : "sRGB",
    "title" : "",
    "description" : "Normal",
    "generator" : "Export Kit v1.2.8"
  },
  "name" : "love shape",
  "layers" : [
    {
      "x" : 0,
      "height" : 612,
      "layers" : [
        {
          "x" : 0,
          "color" : "0xFFFFFF",
          "height" : 612,
          "y" : 0,
          "width" : 612,
          "shapeType" : "rectangle",
          "type" : "shape",
          "name" : "bg_rectangle_1"
        },
        {
          "x" : 49,
          "height" : 480,
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 0,
              "height" : 480,
              "src" : "TZwOgSa.png",
              "y" : 0,
              "width" : 514,
              "type" : "image",
              "name" : "mask_image_1"
            },
            {
              "radius" : "27 \/ 27",
              "color" : "0xACACAC",
              "x" : 233,
              "y" : 205,
              "height" : 53,
              "width" : 53,
              "shapeType" : "ellipse",
              "type" : "shape",
              "name" : "useradd_ellipse1"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 66,
          "width" : 514,
          "type" : "group",
          "name" : "user_image_1"
        }
      ],
      "y" : 0,
      "width" : 612,
      "type" : "group",
      "name" : "loveshape_18"
    }
  ]
};

$(document).ready(function() {

  
     function json(data)

        {
            var width = 0;
            var height = 0;

            let layer1 = data.layers;
            width = layer1[0].width;
            height = layer1[0].height;

            let layer2 = layer1[0].layers;

            for (i = 1; i < layer2.length; i++) {
                var x = layer2[i].x;
                var y = layer2[i].y;
                var src = layer2[i].layers[0].src;
                $(".container").css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');

                var mask = $(".container").mask({
                    maskImageUrl: 'https://i.imgur.com/' + src,
                    onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {

                        img.css({
                            "position": "absolute",
                            "left": x + "px",
                            "top": y + "px"
                        });
                    }
                });

                fileup.onchange = function() {
                    mask.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
                };
            }

        }
json(jsonData);

}); // end of document ready
// jq plugin for mask
(function($) {
    var JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
        }, options);


        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            div;

        container.mousePosition = function(event) {
            return {
                x: event.pageX || event.offsetX,
                y: event.pageY || event.offsetY
            };
        }

        container.selected = function(ev) {
            var pos = container.mousePosition(ev);
            var item = $(".masked-img canvas").filter(function() {
                var offset = $(this).offset()
                var x = pos.x - offset.left;
                var y = pos.y - offset.top;
                var d = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
                return d[0] > 0
            });

            JQmasks.forEach(function(el) {
                var id = item.length > 0 ? $(item).attr("id") : "";
                if (el.id == id)
                    el.item.enable();
                else el.item.disable();
            });
        };

        container.enable = function() {
            draggable = true;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 2
            });
        }

        container.disable = function() {
            draggable = false;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "false");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 1
            });
        }

        container.onDragStart = function(evt) {
            container.selected(evt);
            prevX = evt.clientX;
            prevY = evt.clientY;
   //evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'anything');  
        };

        container.getImagePosition = function() {
            return {
                x: settings.x,
                y: settings.y,
                scale: settings.scale
            };
        };

        container.onDragOver = function(evt) {
            if (draggable && $(canvas).attr("active") === "true") {
                var x = settings.x + evt.clientX - prevX;
                var y = settings.y + evt.clientY - prevY;
                if (x == settings.x && y == settings.y)
                    return; // position has not changed
                settings.x += evt.clientX - prevX;
                settings.y += evt.clientY - prevY;
                prevX = evt.clientX;
                prevY = evt.clientY;
                container.updateStyle();
            }
        };

        container.updateStyle = function() {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                context.beginPath();
                context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
                image = new Image();
                image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                image.src = settings.maskImageUrl;
                image.onload = function() {
                    canvas.width = image.width;
                    canvas.height = image.height;
                    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
                    div.css({
                        "width": image.width,
                        "height": image.height
                    });
                };

                img = new Image();
                img.src = settings.imageUrl;
                img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                img.onload = function() {
                    settings.x = settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
                    settings.y = settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;
                    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
                    context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, img.width * settings.scale, img.height * settings.scale);
                    initImage = false;
                };
            }, 0);
        };

        // change the draggable image
        container.loadImage = function(imageUrl) {
            if (img)
                img.remove();
            // reset the code.
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            prevX = prevY = 0;
            settings.imageUrl = imageUrl;
            initImage = true;
            container.updateStyle();
        };

        // change the masked Image
        container.loadMaskImage = function(imageUrl, from) {
            if (div)
                div.remove();
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
            settings.maskImageUrl = imageUrl;
            div = $("<div/>", {
                "class": "masked-img"
            }).append(canvas);

            div.find("canvas").on('touchstart mousedown', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.onDragStart(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").on('touchend mouseup', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.selected(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").bind("dragover", container.onDragOver);
            container.append(div);
            if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
                settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);
            container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl);
        };
        container.loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
        JQmasks.push({
            item: container,
            id: settings.id
        })
        return container;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.temp {}

.container {
 background: black;
}

.masked-img {
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-top: 30px;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<input id="fileup" type="file" >

<div class="container">
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean instead of choose file button click on image mask you want dialogue box?

Comment: @MehrajKhan That's right....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `label` element with **`for`** attribute, the `for` attribute should match the input file **`id`**

```js
var mask;

let jsonData = {
  "path" : " love shape\/",
  "info" : {
    "author" : "",
    "keywords" : "",
    "file" : "love shape",
    "date" : "sRGB",
    "title" : "",
    "description" : "Normal",
    "generator" : "Export Kit v1.2.8"
  },
  "name" : "love shape",
  "layers" : [
    {
      "x" : 0,
      "height" : 612,
      "layers" : [
        {
          "x" : 0,
          "color" : "0xFFFFFF",
          "height" : 612,
          "y" : 0,
          "width" : 612,
          "shapeType" : "rectangle",
          "type" : "shape",
          "name" : "bg_rectangle_1"
        },
        {
          "x" : 49,
          "height" : 480,
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 0,
              "height" : 480,
              "src" : "e5bcf5edf9e0a4a1df715231f995f878_frame0.png",
              "y" : 0,
              "width" : 514,
              "type" : "image",
              "name" : "mask_image_1"
            },
            {
              "radius" : "27 \/ 27",
              "color" : "0xACACAC",
              "x" : 233,
              "y" : 205,
              "height" : 53,
              "width" : 53,
              "shapeType" : "ellipse",
              "type" : "shape",
              "name" : "useradd_ellipse1"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 66,
          "width" : 514,
          "type" : "group",
          "name" : "user_image_1"
        }
      ],
      "y" : 0,
      "width" : 612,
      "type" : "group",
      "name" : "loveshape_18"
    }
  ]
};

$(document).ready(function() {

  
     function json(data)

        {
            var width = 0;
            var height = 0;

            let layer1 = data.layers;
            width = layer1[0].width;
            height = layer1[0].height;

            let layer2 = layer1[0].layers;

            for (i = 1; i < layer2.length; i++) {
                var x = layer2[i].x;
                var y = layer2[i].y;
                var src = layer2[i].layers[0].src;
                $(".container").css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');
              
           

                var mask = $(".container").mask({
                    maskImageUrl: 'http://piccellsapp.com:1337/parse/files/PfAppId/' + src,
                    onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {

                        img.css({
                            "position": "absolute",
                            "left": x + "px",
                            "top": y + "px"
                        });
                    }
                });

                fileup.onchange = function() {
                    mask.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
                };
            }

        }
json(jsonData);

}); // end of document ready
// jq plugin for mask
(function($) {
    var JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
        }, options);


        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            div;

        container.mousePosition = function(event) {
            return {
                x: event.pageX || event.offsetX,
                y: event.pageY || event.offsetY
            };
        }

        container.selected = function(ev) {
            var pos = container.mousePosition(ev);
            var item = $(".masked-img canvas").filter(function() {
                var offset = $(this).offset()
                var x = pos.x - offset.left;
                var y = pos.y - offset.top;
                var d = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
                return d[0] > 0
            });

            JQmasks.forEach(function(el) {
                var id = item.length > 0 ? $(item).attr("id") : "";
                if (el.id == id)
                    el.item.enable();
                else el.item.disable();
            });
        };

        container.enable = function() {
            draggable = true;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 2
            });
        }

        container.disable = function() {
            draggable = false;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "false");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 1
            });
        }

        container.onDragStart = function(evt) {
            container.selected(evt);
            prevX = evt.clientX;
            prevY = evt.clientY;
   //evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'anything');  
        };

        container.getImagePosition = function() {
            return {
                x: settings.x,
                y: settings.y,
                scale: settings.scale
            };
        };

        container.onDragOver = function(evt) {
            if (draggable && $(canvas).attr("active") === "true") {
                var x = settings.x + evt.clientX - prevX;
                var y = settings.y + evt.clientY - prevY;
                if (x == settings.x && y == settings.y)
                    return; // position has not changed
                settings.x += evt.clientX - prevX;
                settings.y += evt.clientY - prevY;
                prevX = evt.clientX;
                prevY = evt.clientY;
                container.updateStyle();
            }
        };

        container.updateStyle = function() {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                context.beginPath();
                context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
                image = new Image();
                image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                image.src = settings.maskImageUrl;
                image.onload = function() {
                    canvas.width = image.width;
                    canvas.height = image.height;
                    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
                    div.css({
                        "width": image.width,
                        "height": image.height
                    });
                };

                img = new Image();
                img.src = settings.imageUrl;
                img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                img.onload = function() {
                    settings.x = settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
                    settings.y = settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;
                    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
                    context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, img.width * settings.scale, img.height * settings.scale);
                    initImage = false;
                };
            }, 0);
        };

        // change the draggable image
        container.loadImage = function(imageUrl) {
            if (img)
                img.remove();
            // reset the code.
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            prevX = prevY = 0;
            settings.imageUrl = imageUrl;
            initImage = true;
            container.updateStyle();
        };

        // change the masked Image
        container.loadMaskImage = function(imageUrl, from) {
            if (div)
                div.remove();
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
            settings.maskImageUrl = imageUrl;
            div = $("<div/>", {
                "class": "masked-img"
            }).append(canvas);

            div.find("canvas").on('touchstart mousedown', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.onDragStart(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").on('touchend mouseup', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.selected(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").bind("dragover", container.onDragOver);
            container.append(div);
            if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
                settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);
            container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl);
        };
        container.loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
        JQmasks.push({
            item: container,
            id: settings.id
        })
        return container;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.temp {}

.container {
 background: black;
  position: relative;
}

.masked-img {
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-top: 30px;
 position: relative;
}

.file-label {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<input id="fileup" name="fileup" type="file" >

<div class="container">
  <label for="fileup" class="file-label">
    
  </label>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/bearnithi/pen/NJROxr

Comment: Thanks for codepen , but When i click on Mask image, nothing happening.....

Comment: It's perfectly working. which browser you have tried?

Comment: hi, i need to open `file upload dialogue box` when i click on `mask image` , not when i click on `choose file`......

Comment: try it now, i have not saved it correctly. i have updated the codepen z-index property for the label

Comment: yes, now its working , but It should upload only when i click on image, but when i try to drag the uploaded image , than also its allowing to upload image.....

Comment: am changing it pls wait

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189439/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-bear-nithi).

Comment: i accepted your answer as it working for single image , but if there is 2 images , still its not working.... https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/vPXQjZ